# Proving Hardy's theorem: the circular mean of an analytic function is increasing and log-convex

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis, maximum-principle

[image]

This is a problem I am stuck at. First, I guess I have to use the maximum modulus principle to show that $I(r$) is strictly increasing. However $I(r)$ is defined by an integral, not some maximum value of $f(z)$, so I can't see how to apply the maximum modulus principle. Also, how can I find continuous  $\varphi$ if $f(z)$ have zeros? Is  φ guaranteed to be continuous at zeros of $f(z)$?  If these mysteries are solved, then I think I can solve the exercise. Could please anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $I$ is an integral; but so is $F$. Since $F(r)=2\pi I(r)$, the maximum principle applied to $F$ can lead to the result.

The continuity of $\varphi$ isn't really needed for the proof to work: $\varphi$ being measurable is enough to conclude that $F$ is a holomorphic function. Any reasonable integral involving a parameter in a holomorphic way is itself holomorphic, as can be verified using Morera's theorem (integrating over a triangle) and Fubini's theorem (exchanging the order of integration).

Also, the zeros of an analytic function form a discrete set. Hence, there is only a discrete set of values of $r$ for which $f$ has a zero on the circle $|z|=r$. Let's consider a circle without zeros. Then $\varphi(\theta) = |f(re^{i\theta})|/f(re^{i\theta})$ is continuous, and the function 
$$
F(z) = \int_0^{2\pi} f(ze^{i\theta})\varphi(\theta)\,d\theta
$$
is holomorphic in $B(0;R)$. This function is constructed so that
$F(r) = 2\pi I(r)$. 
By the maximum principle, $F(r)\le \max_{|z|=\rho} |F(z)|$ for any $\rho>r$. And since 
$$
\max_{|z|=\rho} |F(z)| \le \int_0^{2\pi} |f(\rho e^{i\theta})|\,d\theta = 2\pi I(\rho)
$$
it follows that $I$ is increasing. In fact, strictly increasing, because nonconstant $f$ implies nonconstant $F$. Here's one way to argue this: if $F$ is constant, then $F(0)=F(r)=2\pi I(r)$. On the other hand, $F(0) = f(0)\int_{0}^{2\pi} \varphi(\theta)\,d\theta$. So, we must have $\varphi \equiv 1$, which means the imaginary part of $f$ is zero on the circle $|z|=r$. But $\operatorname{Im}f$ is harmonic and therefore obeys a maximum principle: it must vanish on a disk, and then $f$ is constant.

So we have $I(r)<I(\rho)$ for all pairs $(r,\rho)$ such that $r<\rho$, except for a discrete set of $r$-values. Since $I$ is continuous, the inequality holds in general; $I$ is strictly increasing.

**Log-convexity** is similar in principle, but I suppose one has to prove [Hadamard's three circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_three-circle_theorem) first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question. Is it just intuitively clear that f(z) being nonconstant implies F (z) being nonconstant? Or can there be some more rigorous proof? If there is, could you explain in more detail?

Comment: And I think, as you mentioned at first, I can work with the concept of measurable and integrable functions and use Morera thm and Fubini thm to prove that F(z) is holomorphic for any value of r.  That is, I dont have to be bothered with the continuity of  φ. Is this correct?

Comment: Also I think there is a gap in your additional proof. I think φ isn't guaranteed to be 1 with the information about F and I you provided.

Comment: To show $\varphi \equiv 1$, notice that you can assume $f(0) > 0$ wlog (to see this, try replacing $f$ by $(|f(0)|/f(0)) f$ in the previous argument; notice, in particular, that $I$ does not change, and all the inequalities should hold).
Now, observe that $\int_0^{2\pi} \varphi(\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{2\pi I(r)}{f(0)} \geq 2\pi$. This is where we used $f(0) > 0$. Hence, $\int_0^{2\pi} \varphi(\theta)\,d\theta = 2\pi$.
Now, using the continuity of $\varphi$ and $|\varphi| = 1$, one can deduce that $\varphi \equiv 1$.